# Mercurial rollback hook?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

I'm writing an extension for which it would be very convenient to be able to perform some logic after a rollback is made.

I looked through all of the documentation I could find on hooks, but I couldn't find a `rollback` hook. I also tried the `post-*` hooks (namely, `post-rollback`), but that also didn't fire. My next step would be to dive into the source, but I thought I'd ask this question in case someone knows.

Is there a rollback hook? And if so, is it possible to wire it up in a Python extension using `uisetup()` or `reposetup()`?

Comment: If it's not in the documentation, then it probably doesn't exist. What are you trying to to?

Comment: @RichardCook: I've built an extension that keeps metadata on commits as I make them (the extension registers itself as a commit hook). Unfortunately, since there is no rollback hook, there's no explicit way for the extension to clean up after itself.

Comment: I scoured the documentation and I can't find anything. You'll probably have to write your own custom command and call that instead of `rollback`.

Comment: @RichardCook: Indeed, it seems like there is no such hook. I ended up writing a custom command, as you said, to clean up incorrect state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around [Mercurial's source code](http://selenic.com/hg/file/a58251c0568f/mercurial/localrepo.py), indeed, the internal rollback function (`_rollback`) doesn't seem to be calling any hooks, so there doesn't seem to be a way to tie in to this event.

I needed the rollback hook because I was writing an extension which maintained metadata about changesets as they occurred. In lieu of being able to tie-in to the rollback event, I ended up writing a custom command as part of the extension to auto-clean any inconsistent state by itself (e.g. a reference to a commit that no longer exists because it was rollback'd).